# Catching Errors in Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

I have a statement that looks something like this

```
if not @user.verified? or @user.credit_card.expired?
  # do stuff
end
```

The problem is the case where the `@user` does not yet have a credit card because `expired?` will raise an exception because of the nil value.

Is there a succinct way to catch the error inline without having to resort to extra if statements?

Comment: check for null first?: i.e. `if @user.credit_card.exists?`

Comment: First of all, use `!` and `||` here instead of `not` and `or`, because they have different precedence.

Comment: better yet, create a `@user.valid_card?` or whatever method, and neatly encapsulate everything there.

Comment: @Nakilon, how would that help me in this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this exception you can use Rails 2.3/3 built-in method: [try](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/releases/rails2dot3/active-support)

```
if not @user.verified? or @user.credit_card.try(:expired?)
  # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The **andand** gem allows for a guarded method invocation if and only if the object is not null.

Your code snippet would look like this:

```
if not @user.verified? or @user.credit_card.andand.expired?
  # do stuff
end
```

You can install it with `gem install andand` and you're good to go.

Website: http://andand.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
@user.credit_card.expired?
```

Would be called a violation of the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). That law states you're allowed to call any method you like on `@user`, but not on `@user.credit_card`.